# odoo 10 product currency

Tags: python, inheritance, currency, odoo-10

Original Code:

```
class name= "product.template"
currency_id = fields.Many2one(
        'res.currency', 'Currency', compute='_compute_currency_id')
```

I just want to inherit currency_id from product_template class. You can see from the picture.

```
class product_price_currency(models.Model):
      _inherit = 'product.template'
      currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', 'Currency', required=True)
```

as you see i just deleted compute function and it should work fine without calling compute function but it does not work. still call compute function. I could not find where is the problem. I hope someone can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write store=True

```
class product_price_currency(models.Model):
      _inherit = 'product.template'
      currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', 'Currency', required=True,store=True)
```

Because in base module this field is **store=False** and you have inherit without **store=True**, due to that reason odoo still considering **store=False** field.

This may help you.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like

```
class product_price_currency(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'product.template'
  currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', 'Currency', required=True,store=True,readonly=False)
```